# Postgresql difference in time based on interval

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, `time_slots`, which has a column `start_time`. My `users` table has a column, `hours_before` (int), which is the number of hours before the `start_time` to receive a notification.

I'm running a job every 5 minutes that checks the time slots that have a `start_time` which is now + `hours_before`. All my datetimes are store in UTC. I can't figure out the correct `where` clause to get the appropriate time slots.

Right now I'm passing in the current time in UTC as a string rather than doing something like `current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'`.

```sql
(extract(epoch from starts_at) - extract(epoch from (date '2020-11-09 06:20:00' + (users.hours_before * INTERVAL '1 hour')))) = 0
```

Here is a test query to see what the values are inside of a `select`. In this example, `(6 * INTERVAL '1 hour')` would be where `users.hours_before` would be. I'm using a static `6` while tinkering.

```sql
select
  (extract(epoch from "starts_at") - extract(epoch from date '2020-11-09 06:20:00')) / 3600 as hours,
  (extract(epoch from "starts_at") - extract(epoch from (date '2020-11-09 06:20:00' + (6 * INTERVAL '1 hour')))) as other_interval,
  *
from
  "time_slots"
where
  "starts_at" > '2020-11-09 06:20:00'
order by hours asc;
```

For example, the following query has the same `hours` and `other_interval` values as the above query, despite the date being `2020-11-09 10:00:00` instead of `2020-11-09 06:00:00`. Shouldn't those columns be 4 hours different since they change by 4 hours?

```sql
select
  (extract(epoch from "starts_at") - extract(epoch from date '2020-11-09 10:00:00')) / 3600 as hours,
  (extract(epoch from "starts_at") - extract(epoch from (date '2020-11-09 10:00:00' + (6 * INTERVAL '1 hour')))) as other_interval,
  *
from
  "time_slots"
where
  "starts_at" >= '2020-11-09 06:00:00'
order by hours asc;
```

Comment: `date '2020-11-09 10:00:00'` loses the time part because a `date` doesn't have a time. You want `timestamp '2020-11-09 10:00:00'`

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you first subtract the values, then get the epoch? `extract(epoch from starts_at - timestamp '2020-11-09 10:00:00'`)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `timestamp` does the trick. To answer your second question, because I have no idea what I'm doing! ha, thanks for the direction.